# How to efficiently fire an event each time a different page is accessed

Tags: php, events, laravel-5, controller

im working on an application from my companies previous developer and im at the point now where the boss has asked me to log which user has accessed what page. So I've set up some events and listeners to get the job done as i have been doing for all the other logs but there is a problem.

If i was to fire an event the way I've been doing it up till now id have to re-write the code to fire an event for every separate method that returns a page, but right now this is the only viable option i see because then i can customise the information that i put into the event log (I need the ability to customise information that's being pushed to the event / listener). **Example Below**

```
 public function showCreateAccount()
    {

        // NEW EVENT HERE
        //I need the account types for this page and the status types
        $account_types = AccountController::getTypes();
        $status_types  = StatusController::getTypes();
        $timezone_types = TimezoneController::getTypes();
        $currency_types = CurrencyController::getTypes();

        return view('create.account')->with('account_types', $account_types)
            ->with('status_types', $status_types)
            ->with('currency_types', $currency_types)
            ->with('timezone_types', $timezone_types);
    }

    public function showCreateRevenue()
    {
        // NEW EVENT HERE...
        $revenue_types = RevenueController::getTypes();
        return view('create.income')->with('revenue_types', $revenue_types);
    }

    public function showCreateIncomeWithID($id)
    {
        // NEW EVENT HERE
        return view('create.income')->with('account_id', $id);
    }

    public function showCreateExpense()
    {
        // NEW EVENT HERE, ETC ETC
        $expense_types = ExpenseController::getTypes();
        return view('create.outcome')->with('expense_types', $expense_types);
    }
```

Now this will work fine i assume but what im worried about is that this method isnt "good practice" surely there must be an alternative to writing a new event in each and every function whilst still being able to pass relevant information about what page has been accessed?

If i am wrong please correct me if not your answers are welcome

Comment: You could possibly do a `debug_backtrace()` on the view and save that to `json` in the log? That might be slow but it would only run once at the end.

Comment: @Rasclatt hahaha your name tho :D, but thanks that's a cool function I didn't know about, ill see if I can implement it at all.